# explanation for the exported express module, it's structure and the difference between app object and express object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to learn expressjs, however, I managed to confuse myself out. I would appreciate if someone can shed some light. basically how can the exported express module be both a function and an object??

I console.log(express)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6i5p7.png) in my app.js and came up to this. Having looked at the expressjs source code I got even more confused on what is going on under the hood. I think I shouldnt have looked very deep inside. My main questions being:

- is express a constructor function, if so why dont we use '
- what is the difference between the "app" and the "express"? (I just cant seem to grasp what they mean by express() being a top-level
  function...)

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`express` is a *function*. When called, it *returns* an express router instance (That's what you've stored in `app`). As functions are objects in JavaScript, the `express` function has additional properties, e.g. `express.static`.

```
 function express() {
    return { get(url, handler) { /*...*/ }, /*...*/ };
 }

 express.static = function() { /*...*/ };

 const app = express();

 app.get("path", (req, res) => { /*...*/ });
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind answer, it all clicks now! Now as I am new to all this (as I am sure you have guessed), I was wondering if this is a common/standard/convention practice outside of the frameworks and libraries, or should I stick to creating a named object with methods and properties, i.e, for example, writing myObj.express() myObj.static. Just for the sake of best practices  :)

Comment: I'd say that express is kinda special in that regard ... cause the instances ain't really *instances*. If you want to do OOP, nowadays I'd use `class`. But ... that's all just style, other things work too.